# jquery .html doesn't process certain tags and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

At the moment I'm working on a mobile website that stores pages in a local database. At the bottom are some basic buttons to navigate to other pages and when you press them I wanted to use jquery's .html function to replace the body content with other html strings from the database. The problem I found is when we go to our contact form page the user can't really use the form fields. They show up, but they're not clickable. I've also noticed that you can't execute javascript functions that are loaded in trough the .html function.

Hopefully you can help me with this problem or suggest a workaround. Thanks

Comment: Markup? javascript code? anyway read about delegate events.

Comment: What technology are you using on the server, I've seen similar issues when people try to cache ASP.NET pages/controls.

Answer (score 0):

Some jQuery functions strip out script and style tags (e.g. `.replace()`). That isn't a bug but documented somewhere – unfortunately I can't find that piece of documentation right now.

But that should be no problem in the case of form fields. They should get inserted without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ztrsX/) that illustrates your problem.
Explanation:
jQuery html seems to not process some tags, although it does. The problem is when trying to execute jQuery UI related functions on an element **not within the DOM**
the exemple above shows the difference between calling **button** jqueryUI function after and before appending the element to the DOM
a generic workaround to solve this problem is:

```
var div = $('<div></div>').hide().appendTo('body');
```

then do whatever you want with the **div**

Comment: Hey I tried your solution, but it didn't work. Any more suggestions mate?

Comment: show us your code in order to help you.. maybe you have another issue in your code